# How to get the count of "Message" and distinct count of "name" from json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have json file as shown:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "serial_no": 1,
            "name": "HD Televizija",
            "id": "103525823050602_389832151148675",
            "date": "11/18/13 1:57",
            "message": "Zabava uz Philipsov Hue sustav rasvjete. cc Philips hue",
            "type": "photo",
            "like_count": 0,
            "comment_count": 0,
            "share_count": 0
        },
        {
            "serial_no": 2,
            "name": "Garmental",
            "id": "107057885997763_398139340317956",
            "date": "12/7/13 5:33",
            "message": "Setting the mood based on a photo? With Philips hue any photo on your smart phone becomes a palette to paint with light! Fabio Viviani is on to something!   Find out more HERE  http://bit.ly/1g7hAMy'",
            "type": "photo",
            "like_count": 0,
            "comment_count": 0,
            "share_count": 1
        },
        {
            "serial_no": 3,
            "name": "Expert Deurne",
            "id": "194564077345567_403082633156960",
            "date": "12/17/13 22:00",
            "message": "Nu een Philips India 55,
          "type": "link",
            "like_count": 0,
            "comment_count": 0,
            "share_count": 0
        }
```

I have to plot the count of messages and the distinct count of names as bar graph something like this:
 [image]

To plot the graph I need function which can count the total messages and distinct count of names MONTH/YEAR wise. How do I increment the date value which is passed as parameter
I have tried this:

```
function(/*paramater*/) {
    var nameArray = data.countBy(data, function (data) { return data.name; });
    var nameCount = nameArray.length; //will give distinct count of names
    var msgCount = data.msg.length;
}
```

How can I get the count of msgs and distinct count of names for a given month/year??

Comment: Won't the msg count and the name count be the same?

Comment: @Andy no coz there can be entries with same name but different message. and he wants it with unique names

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is filter the objects array on the date, remove the duplicate names and return an object that gives you the count of names and messages.

```
function getData(obj, searchmonth, searchyear) {
    var arr = obj.data.filter(function (el) {
        var date = el.date.split(' ')[0].split('/');
        return searchmonth === date[0] && searchyear === date[2];
    });

    var unique = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
      if (p.indexOf(c.name) < 0) p.push(c.name);
      return p;
    }, []);

    return { msgs: arr.length, names: unique.length };
}

// pass in the data object, month and year
getData(obj, '12', '13'); // { msgs: 3, names: 2 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zc0nh1rj/6/) - note that in my example I added an extra object with a duplicate name to show it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var filterByMonthYear = function(m,y){
   return data.filter(function(x){
      var d = new Date(x.date)
      if((d.getMonth() + 1) == m && d.getYear() == y){
        return x;
      }
   })
}
var filtered = filterByMonthYear(12,13),
    msgs = [],
    names = [];

for(i in filtered){
  var t = filtered[i];
  if(t.message != ""){ // remove empty messages, remove this if you dont want.
    msgs.push(t.message);
  }
  if(t.name != ""){ // remove empty names, remove this if you dont want.
    names.push(t.name)
  }
}

// filter unique names
names = names.filter(function(name,index,self){
  return self.indexOf(name) === index;
})

var totalUniqueNames = names.length,
    totalMessage = msgs.length;

console.log(totalUniqueNames, totalMessage);
```